# rsyslog conditional forwarding for remote logs de-formatting the date and time in the log file

Tags: rsyslog, rsyslogd

I've another question about the conditional forwarding of logs via rsyslog.conf, i have below configuration.

```
# cat  /etc/rsyslog.conf
##########################################################################################
# rsyslog configuration file For TCC & TPC
##########################################################################################
#### MODULES ####
$ModLoad imuxsock        # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal       # provides access to the systemd journal
$ModLoad imudp           # Provides UDP syslog reception
$UDPServerRun 514        # Provides UDP syslog reception
# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
$template tcc-logs, "/data/SYSTEMS/%HOSTNAME%/messages.log"
$template noi-logs, "/data/noiter/%HOSTNAME%/messages.log"

#####################################################################
# Custom conditional Forwarding of messages to the syslog Directory #
###################################################################
if $fromhost startswith "sj-" then -?tcc-logs
& stop

if $fromhost startswith "noi-" then -?noi-logs
& stop


##################################################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES                        ####
#################################################
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog                                 # Where to place auxiliary files
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat        # Use default timestamp format
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf                            # Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$OmitLocalLogging on                                            # local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state                             # File to store the position in the journal

#### RULES ############################################
# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.#
# Don't log private authentication messages!        #
####################################################
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none    ?tcc-logs
authpriv.*       ?tcc-logs                                      # The authpriv file has restricted access.
```

In the above configuration, i'm trying to ask rsyslog for conditional forwarding of logs with below points:

1. If any upcoming host to `rsyslog` which startswith "`sj`"  then it should go to "`/data/SYSTEMS/` Directory " which will create another Directory with hostname and then will create a `messages.log` on this So, the complete file path will be like `/data/SYSTEMS/sj-hosts_1/messages.log` .
2. Similarly, If any upcoming host to `rsyslog` which startswith `noi-` then it should go to `/data/noiter/` Directory " which will create another Directory with hostname and then will create a `messages.log` on this So, the complete file path will be like `/data/noiter/noi-hosts_1/messages.log` .

The above two points meets the results However the problem is the `messages.log` in the above case creating the date and time into different format than the default, example is below:

```
2019-01-25T23:20:01-08:00 noi-hosts_1 CROND[8541]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)

2019-01-25T23:20:01-08:00 noi-hosts_1 CROND[8542]: (root) CMD (LANG=C LC_ALL=C
```

**While the default & required format should be as follows:**

---

```
Jan 25 20:23:58 noi-hosts_1 CROND[8541]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jan 25 20:23:58 noi-hosts_1 CROND[8542]: (root) CMD (LANG=C LC_ALL=C
```

---

### Note:

> When i don't use conditional forwarding then i used to get the
>   correct /default one as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional rules `if $fromhost ...` are near the start of the configuration, and use the default logging style, which for rsyslog is now `RSYSLOG_FileFormat`. You change the default to the wanted `RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat` later on, but this only applies to any following rules.

So simply move your conditional rules further down in the file, to just after the comment block `#### RULES ...`